# Hiding admin menu items in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to hide certain admin menu items in Wordpress from all users except one (myself).

I can find various tutorials but they mostly hide on user roles rather than users.

I have found this from the Wordpress codex:

```
<?php 
function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    remove_menu_page( $menu_slug );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
?>
```

But I don't fully understand it, plus I think I'll need to add some more PHP to it to essentially make the code say:

**If user isn't shaun@seedcreativity.co.uk (Me!)**

**Then remove these menu items:**

**ItemID 1, ItemID 2, ItemID 3, etc...**

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove Posts menu for given e-mail with:

```
function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    if ( get_currentuserinfo()->user_email != 'shaun@seedcreativity.co.uk' )
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
```

**It will not prevent users from using removed pages if they can guess proper URL e.g. /wp-admin/edit.php**

Answer (score 15):

You can check for the user id:

```
// admin_init action works better than admin_menu in modern wordpress (at least v5+)
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {


  global $user_ID;

  if ( $user_ID != 1 ) { //your user id

   remove_menu_page('edit.php'); // Posts
   remove_menu_page('upload.php'); // Media
   remove_menu_page('link-manager.php'); // Links
   remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php'); // Comments
   remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page'); // Pages
   remove_menu_page('plugins.php'); // Plugins
   remove_menu_page('themes.php'); // Appearance
   remove_menu_page('users.php'); // Users
   remove_menu_page('tools.php'); // Tools
   remove_menu_page('options-general.php'); // Settings
  }
}
```

Comment: Great: admin_menu won't work in current wp version, while admin_init works perfect

Answer (score 6):

You can try this code.

```
function remove_menus(){
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( 'shaun@seedcreativity.co.uk' !==  $current_user->user_email){
        remove_menu_page( 'item1' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'item2' ); 
    }

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

item1, item2 will your page name 
for example 
http://test.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=item1
http://test.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=item2

Comment: Thats Perfect, thank you :) If I wanted to add a second user, other than myself, how would I add that? I tried adding:  . 'new email' after mine, but it didn't work... Is it s simple add on like that?

Comment: function remove_menus(){
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( in_array( $current_user->user_email, array('firstuser@email.com','seconduser@email.com',)) ){
        remove_menu_page( 'item1' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'item2' ); 
    }

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
use it like this for multiple users

Comment: you can use this plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-admin-menu/

Answer (score 0):

** To hide woocommerce, marketing, acf fields and analytics menu use below code**

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_menu_pages' );
function remove_menu_pages() {


  global $user_ID;

  if ( $user_ID != 1 ) { 
   remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=acf-field-group' );
   remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product' );
   remove_menu_page('woocommerce');
   remove_menu_page('wc-admin&path=/analytics/overview');
   remove_menu_page('woocommerce-marketing');
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not acceptable to copy and paste the answer that was generated by AI. This is a form of exploitation of the developer, who worked hard to provide the answer. It is important to respect the hard work and effort that goes into creating and maintaining AI systems, and to use them responsibly. Instead of simply copying and pasting the answer, try to understand the solution and explain it in your own words, or give credit to the source of the information. @user58006.